# dynamic margin based on jQuery window.width()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a little problem with a jQuery function. I need to add a margin to some element when the window.width is < 580px and i need to remove it when the window.width is larger. Here is the problem, the first part of the function work well, not the second.

```
var Wwidth= $(window).width();

if ( Wwidth < 582) {
    $( window ).resize(function() {  
    var nWwidth=$( document ).width();
    var marginL = (nWwidth - 292)/2;

    $('.hub-item').css('margin-left',marginL +'px');
    });
}
else {
     $( window ).resize(function() {  
    $('.hub-item').css('margin-left','0px');
    });

}
```

I have no mystakes in the console but the margin are not to 0. 
Thanks u all!

EDIT :
Correct code :

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var Wwidth= $(this).width();
    if (Wwidth < 582) {
        var nWwidth=$( window ).width();
        var marginL = (nWwidth - 292)/2;

        $('.hub-item').css('margin-left',marginL +'px');
    }
    else {
        $('.hub-item').css('margin-left','0px');
    }
});
```

Thanks all!

Comment: I think you need to wrap your code with the `$(window).resize`. Not the `resize` inside an `if` statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your `if` statement *within* the `$(window).resize()` function, and recalculate `Wwidth` every time:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var Wwidth = $(this).width();

    if (Wwidth < 582) {
        ...
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Thx working well, i also replace document by window to avoid a bug

Comment: @lovis91 if this is the answer please mark it as such.